# Need Verification on a Modulus Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So basically I have to prove: n ≡ 1 (mod 4) if and only if n ≡ 1 (mod 8) or n ≡ 5 (mod 8).

Is this a sufficient proof: $4 \times 2n + 1= 8 \times n + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod {8}$ where $n$ is an integer and $4 \times (2n + 1) + 1 = 8n + 4 + 1 \equiv 5 \pmod {8}$

Comment: You should be *explicitly* mention the case analyis: $\,n = 4m+1\,$ so $\,m\,$ is even or odd, so $\ldots$. You also need to handle the (easier) converse (or make bidirectional (iff) deductions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you're re-using $n$, which is confusing. Use say $k$ instead. And start your proof with a little more explanation:

---

$n\equiv1 \bmod 4$ means that $n=4k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

if $k$ is odd with $k=2j+1, n=4(2j+1)+1 = 8j+5$, which gives $n\equiv 5 \bmod 8$

if $k$ is even with $k=2j, n=4(2j)+1 = 8j+1$, which gives $n\equiv 1 \bmod 8$

---

I think that's what you meant, but a little more explanation and using new symbols would make it a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

We know $n=4k+1$. If $k=2c$ is even $n=4(2c)+1=8c+1$

If $k=2c+1$ is odd $n=4(2c+1)+1=8c+5$

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Thank you